# Como recuperar o valor de vários dropdownlist (somente preenchidos)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como posso recuperar o valor de diversos dropdown (somente os preenchidos)

A função abaixo não funciona corretamente. Por exemplo, se eu seleciono somente o segundo combo tem como saida: **,2**
Ele pega o vazio como se fosse seleção. Tem como contornar isso?

```html
    $("div.container-fluid").on("change", "select.dropDown", function() {

 var selectData = [];

        $('select.dropDown option:selected').each(function(i, selected){
            var selectData[i] = $(selected).val();

        });
});
```

Meu html está assim:

```html
<select class="dropDown" id="column_1">
                 <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Please select</option>
                            <option value="1">A</option>
                            <option value="2">B</option>
                            <option value="3">C</option>
                            <option value="4">D</option>
</select>

<select class="dropDown" id="column_2">
                 <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Please select</option>
                            <option value="1">A</option>
                            <option value="2">B</option>
                            <option value="3">C</option>
                            <option value="4">D</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que queres usar o `.filter()` cuja função é reduzir uma array aos elementos que veirificam uma dada condição.

O teu código poderia ser assim:

```
$("div.container-fluid").on("change", "select.dropDown", function () {
    var selectedCombos = $('select.dropDown').filter(function () {
        return this.value;
    });
});
```

e se quiseres, em vez do elemento `select` o próprio valor nessa array então podes usar o `.map()` assim:

```
$("div.container-fluid").on("change", "select.dropDown", function () {
    var selectedValues = $('select.dropDown').filter(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wong62pn/

É curioso, e talvez confuso, que ambos os métodos têm `return this.value;`. No primeiro caso ele verifica se o value existe, caso não remove o elemento da array. No segundo caso (`.map()`) o valor que o `return` dá é o que é substituído na array.

Comment: Sergio, poderia explicar o porquê de não usar: .filter(function (i, selected) na segunda opção? Outra questão: o parâmetro "selected" é a seleção do dropdown neste caso?

Comment: @BrunoNascimento o jQuery coloca disponivel o elemento iterado em dois sitios. Meio desnecessário mas ambos o `this` e o `select` no caso de usares argumentos `(i, select)` na função iteradora.  Optei por usar o `this`, mas se usares `(i, selected)` é bom na mesma, até mais conforme a API do javascript nativo. Respondi à tua pergunta?